# Пройтись по масссиву, проверяя условие

Tags: c#, массивы

Помогите разобраться с массивом:
Есть массив `Array[i]`, мне нужно найти в этом массиве все элементы, которые отвечают условию. Например:

```
if (Array[i].мое_условие_здесь (Array[i]))
{...};
```

Сейчас, у меня работает так:

```
if (Array[0].мое_условие_здесь (Array[1]))  
{...};  
if (Array[1].мое_условие_здесь (Array[2]))  
{...};  
if (Array[1].мое_условие_здесь (Array[3]))  
{...};  
if (Array[4].мое_условие_здесь (Array[5]))  
{...};
```

А, мне надо пройтись по всему массиву. Вот только как это написать?
**Дополнение**
Следующий код:

```
for(int i=0; i<Array.Lenght-1; i++)  
if(Array[i].ваше_условие_здесь (Array[i+1]) {...};
```

выполняет ваше_условие_здесь,но лишь в близлежащих индексах,то есть,работает с [0]и[1],[1]и[2],[3]и[4] и так далее,но нужно,что бы условие принималось по всем индексам,и работало даже с [0]и[9],[4]и[1],[4]и[9] и так далее,со всеми вариантами.
Может стоить начать новую тему или оставить все здесь?

Comment: В первом вашем примере кода вы сравниваете i-тый элемент с i-тым, но уже во втором примере кода в первой строчке сравниваете i-тый с i+1 ... дальше вообще не понятно какой элемент выбирается для сравнения с другим ... Мне кажется вы напутали что-то с индексами элементов.

Comment: Я хочу сравнивать все элементы индексов сразу,то есть перебрать индексы массива

Comment: @Педаль: а цикл `for` вы уже проходили? Или `while`?

Comment: вот как раз сейчас и прохожу

Comment: ну, чтобы использовать в таком виде как ты предлагаешь, то тебе как минимум нужно стандартный класс `Array` расширять. Что не рекомендуется делать.

Comment: @Сахарок: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx А почему не рекомендуется?

Comment: @VladD 1. Чтобы не засорять системные библиотеки 2. Чтобы не случалось вероятных конфликтов имен. 3. Чтобы случайно не сломать её

Comment: @Сахарок, глупости говорите. Расширения ничего не засорять, кроме Вашей же библиотеки. Область имен подключать никто не заставляет же. Отключить, например, System.Linq и не будет кучи расширения, но никто не помешает воспользоваться напрямую классом Enumerable.

Конфликты имен и к самих Microsoft присутствует. Вы им посоветуете убрать расширения из стандарта? :-)

"Сломать" - без комментариев...

Comment: @Spawn В моей библиотеке - ничего. Но мы говорили вообще-то о стандартных (встроенных, предустановленных) библиотеках.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по описанию вам нужно два цикла.

```
        for (var j = 1; j < myArray.Length; j++)
        {
            for (var i = 1; i < myArray.Length; i++)
            {
                if (myArray[i] > myArray[j]) // здесь заменить на условие
                {
                    //здесь вставить действия для данного условия
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Не уверен, что этого требует условие задачи, но есть вероятность, что надо исключить дублирующиеся проверки, если способ сравнения элементов массива симметричен.

Comment: @navispb
надо понимать,что условие надо заменить так:  

if(Array[i].ваше_условие_здесь (Array[J]){...};
верно?

Comment: Да. У вас, правда, скобка закрывающая пропущена. И как правильно было замечено товарищем Modus, если в задаче нельзя допускать сравнение вида "(Array[0].мое_условие_здесь (Array[0]))", то нужно это исключить вставив условие проверки i != j

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 1; i < myArray.Length; i++)
{
  if (MyCondition(myArray[i - 1], myArray[i])) // проверка условия для соседних элементов массива
    // делаете, что Вам нужно
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0; i<Array.Lenght - 1; i++)
{
    //ваши проверки
}
```

Comment: прошу прощение,я не правильно написал условие проблемы.
моя проверка выглядит так: if (Array[0].мое_условие_здесь(Array[1]));

Comment: а зачем минусовать Макса Жукова?

Comment: Ну тогда 

    for(int i=0; i<Array.Lenght-1; i++)
      if(Array[i].ваше_условие_здесь (Array[i+1]) {...};

Comment: да, пардоньте, Length - 1. исправил.

Comment: ваше_условие_здесь работает лишь с соседним индексом [0]и[1],[1]и[2]и так далее,а загвоздка в том,что бы это условие (ваше_условие_здесь) работало для всех индексов,не только для рядом стоящего,например [0]и[9],[1]и[7],[1]и[4]и так далее,что бы все индексы перебрать друг с другом

Comment: Так бы сразу и сказали. Тогда вложенные циклы надо делать.

Comment: догадываюсь что вложенным циклом,а вот как именно?